# Need find command solution for ms-dos application?

Tags: dos

I have some `*.bat` file containing `find` command to extract some particular line.

for example, if my input text file contains something like:

```
Login time : XX:XX
username - XXXXXX
Login time : YY:YY
username - YYYYYYY
```

using username lest say:

```
find /I "XXXXXX" input.txt | find /I "XXXXXX" > output.txt
```

I am able to get the username but not sure how to get the correct login time for only the searched user name?

Comment: is that really DOS or is it the Windows Command Line?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` (and  `findstr`) can't process line feeds. They handle each line on its own. So you have to write a script that remembers the last line, checks the current line for the searchstring and prints both the last line and the current line, if the searchstring is found.

I used `findstr` instead of `find`, because it's more secure (`find "XXXXXX"` would also find `XXXXXXY`). See `findstr /?` for the switches `i`, `x` and `c`.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "search=xxxxxx"

for /f "delims=" %%a in (t.txt) do (
  echo %%a|findstr /ixc:"username - %search%" >nul && echo !lastline! %%a
  set "lastline=%%a"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you are actually working on [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) (`cmd.exe`) rather than on [dos](/questions/tagged/dos) (`COMMAND.COM`), you could use [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html), which allows to define a multi-line search string, although it only returns the first line in case of a match, but the next one is is always the same anyway, so it might not be needed.

This Windows [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) shows what I mean:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Get Carriage-Return (CR) character:
for /F %%C in ('copy /Z "%~f0" nul') do set "CR=%%C"
rem // Get Line-Feed (LF) character:
(set LF=^
%= blank line =%
)
rem // Enable delayed expansion to be able to use CR and LF:
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem /* Specify a multi-line search string, which must literally reflect the actual
rem    line-break (that is CR + LF for a DOS/Windows text file); `findstr` returns
rem    only the first line when it encounters a match: */
findstr /I /R /C:"!CR!!LF!username - XXXXXX$" "input.txt" > "output.txt"
rem /* This is needed to get the second line of the multi-line match too
rem    (replace this by the commented out line in case you expect multiple entries for
rem    the searched user, because you would get multiple equal user name entries; the
rem    commented out line ensures that there is a single user name entry at the end): */
findstr /I /R /C:"^username - XXXXXX$" "input.txt" >> "output.txt"
rem findstr /I /R /C:"^username - XXXXXX$" "input.txt" | findstr /I /R /V /C:"!CR!!LF!username" >> "output.txt"
```

---

*N. B.:*
I guess you are using two `find` commands to get rid of the header that the first one produces; you could however use the following instead:

```cmd
rem // Input redirection `<` prevents `find` from returning a header:
find /I "XXXXXX" < "input.txt" > "output.txt"
```

Comment: works fine, if there is just one entry per user. If there are several users, it first lists all the timestamps, only then several times the username. You can remove the second `findstr` and just `echo XXXXXX` before the first one. If the format is ok for the OP, this should be the fastest possible method (with `cmd`). (Nice trick to include the `CRLF` into the search string)

Comment: Thanks, @Stephan, I have to admit I didn't think of that; I extended the code a bit to cover such cases, assuming that multiple equal user name entries are not needed in the file anyway…